# Loop through an array indexed by chars

Tags: arrays, pascal

My question is simple. How do you loop through an array like this in Pascal?

```
P : array[char] of list;
```

[Here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/for-in_loop) I found some promising information about for-in loops, but they don't seem to compile with fpc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
type
   ch_array = array[char] of 1..26;
var
   alphabet: ch_array;
   c: char;
 begin
    ...
   for c:= 'A' to 'Z' do
    alphabet[c] := ord(c);  
   (* the ord() function returns the ordinal values *)
```

More information can be checked at this link.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_arrays.htm

Thanks

Comment: Can you correct your code so it will compile (for the benefit of future readers)? `Ord` is an intrinsic function, not an array; `ord[m]` is incorrect. Also, you have no variable `m` in your code anywhere. (I realize your answer has been accepted, but it has invalid content that may be confusing to future readers who find this in a search.)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for noticing that. I changed ord[m] to ord[c]. Since ord() function just return ordinal value and that statement in our case is just an assignment operation so it could be anything like `alphabet[c] := c;`

Comment: No, it's still partially wrong. :-) `Ord` is a **function**, and you don't call a function with `[]`; you call it with `()`, so the correct code is `Ord(c)`. I fixed it for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over the full range, try

```
var c : char;
for c:=low(P) to high(p) do
   OperationOn(P[c]);
```

or (more modern, requires 2.6.x+)

```
var t: list
for t in P do
  writeln(t.count);
```